# How to exclude contents from migration

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm using Migrate to import entities.

I want to exclude rows based on a custom plugin (my source has a "url" field and I've to check if this url contains a "www.mysite.com" string: if not, the rows must be ignored).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This hook might be the solution it excludes different contents from migrating:

```
use Drupal\migrate\Row;
use Drupal\migrate\Plugin\MigrateSourceInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\Plugin\MigrationInterface;

function hook_migrate_prepare_row(Row $row, MigrateSourceInterface $source, MigrationInterface $migration) {
  // Ignore content types from being migrated.
  if ($migration->id() == 'd6_node_type') {
    $ignore_content_types = array('content_type1', 'content_type2');
    if (in_array($row->getSource()['type'], $ignore_content_types)) {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }

  // Ignoring content of 4 content types.
  $ignore_content_types_content = array('d6_node__content_type1', 'd6_node__content_type2');
  if (in_array($migration->id(), $ignore_content_types_content)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ops, there are hooks! I was looking for migrate plugins

Comment: There is a "Skip on empty" plugin, in core, that could be used to create a custom plugin that checks value: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21SkipOnEmpty.php/class/SkipOnEmpty

It's very simple, I can add a simple private method where check values.

Comment: I've not tried it but it should works.

Answer (score 0):

Via yml approach you would do as following:

```
process:
  name:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: row
      source: name
    -
      plugin: get
      source: name
```